# Use Join to get record info without returning the row in the query

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables (Apple and Bid). I want to return all rows from A based on a given condition, and I want to get a single value from table B. It will help if I show what I'm trying to do:

```
Apple
ID
Name
Type

Bid
bid_id
Type
```

I want to return all records from A where the ID matches a given ID AND I want to get the bid_id associated with each record pulled from table A.

So, my query looks something like this:

```
"Select A.ID, A.Name, A.Type, B.bid_id
FROM Apple A
LEFT JOIN Bid B on B.Type = A.Type
Where A.ID = 35";
```

There is only one record in the `Apple` table with an id of 35. However, since there are three tables in the `Bid` table whose type matches that of Apple # 35's type, three records are being returned.

To clarify, only *one* record should be being returned.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any rule for which `Bid` should be returned, or can it be a random one?  Which database are you using?

Comment: This is a MYSQL database. And no, Any bid can be returned, but only a specific Apple record may be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySQL:

```
Select A.ID, A.Name, A.Type, B.bid_id
FROM Apple A
LEFT JOIN Bid B
  ON B.Type = A.Type
WHERE A.ID = 35
GROUP BY A.ID
```

That will return one of the `bid_id`'s. If you have some rule as to which `bid_id` to choose, you can implement it using aggregation functions - e.g., MIN, MAX, and more complex rules can be implemented as well.

Comment: This did just what I wanted it to. Thanks

Comment: I would have, it makes me wait though ;)

Answer (score 1):

Arbitrarily choosing to return the MIN value:

```
Select A.ID, A.Name, A.Type, MIN(B.bid_id)
    FROM Apple A
        LEFT JOIN Bid B 
            ON B.Type = A.Type
    WHERE A.ID = 35
    GROUP BY A.ID, A.Name, A.Type;
```

Comment: Why do you group by all three fields from `A`?

Comment: @Evan: The `GROUP BY` is for the `MIN` function used in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: @JoeStefanelli, actually, mostly it is for getting only one row per `A.ID`.

Comment: @Shedal: I answered before the RDBMS (MySQL) was specified, so I answered in a way that would be acceptable for other engines, such as SQL Server, which is stricter on GROUP BY requirements than MySQL.

Comment: Why not just use "limit 1" then, like a user above used? What's the difference? I thought Group By should only be used when grouping large amounts of data into categories.

Comment: @Evan `LIMIT 1` assumes exactly one row will be returned from the `Apple` table, which I believe is a valid assumption in this specific case, but I answered in a more generic way to support the possibility that more than one row could match.

Comment: @Evan, LIMIT limits the whole resultset to 1 record. Grouping "limits" per ID (in your case).

Comment: I see, so I actually think Group By is the smarter way to go then.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're looking for up to one random bid, the fastest option would be `limit 1`:

```
select  A.ID
,       A.Name
,       A.Type
,       B.bid_id
from    Apple A
left join
        Bid B 
on      B.Type = A.Type
where   A.ID = 35
limit   1
```